# basic flask program returning 500 server error

Tags: python, flask, return

Trying to setup a basic flask (Python) app in PyCharm

Below is the basic 'Hello world' app modified with some Python I already know.
I changed the return `'Hello world!'` to `return contacts` to try and print out my dictionaries onto the blank page, but I'm getting a 500 server error.

What is my basic mistake?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    contacts = dict()
    johnSmith = dict()
    jasonBourne = dict()
    lisbethSalander = dict()

    johnSmith['label'] = 'John Smith'
    johnSmith['phone'] = '(222) 333-4444'
    johnSmith['email'] = 'john@johnsmith.net'

    jasonBourne['label'] = 'Jason Bourne'
    jasonBourne['phone'] = '(333) 444-5555'
    jasonBourne['email'] = 'jason@cia.gov'

    lisbethSalander['label'] = 'Lisbeth Salander'
    lisbethSalander['phone'] = '(444) 555-6666'
    lisbethSalander['email'] = 'lsalander@gmail.com'

    contacts['1'] = johnSmith
    contacts['2'] = jasonBourne
    contacts['3'] = susanBoom

    print contacts
    return contacts
    # return 'Hello world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application
```

Looks like error happened in app.py line 203

```
try:
    request_started.send(self)
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
    if rv is None:
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
except Exception as e:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return something Flask recognizes as a response from a view.  This includes [`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template), [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.jsonify), or a custom [`Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Response) object.  In your case it looks like you want to return a JSON object, so use [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.jsonify).

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a dictionary; Flask requires you to return a string, a response object or a valid WSGI application. See the [response rules](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#about-responses).

You could either return a string version of the dictionary, hand the dictionary to a template, or return a JSON response. You didn't state what you *expected* to be returned, however.

If you just want to see your contacts 'on a blank page', convert the dictionary to a string:

```
return str(contacts)
```