# Send form data to MongoDB using Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm having troubles sending my `form` data to MongoDB with a Flask setup. The form looks something like this: **https://jsfiddle.net/8gqLtv7e**

On the client-side, I see no errors. But when I submit the form, I receive a 500 Internal Server Error and I'm having a hard time finding the solution. The problem is the last line below in my `views.py` file:

```
@app.route('/recordReport', methods=['POST'])
def recordReport():
    homeReportsCollection = db["reports"]
    address=request.form.get['address']
    rgbImage=request.form.get['rgb']
    homeReportsCollection.insert({'address':address, 'rgb':rgbImage})
```

Because if I replace that with `return json.dumps({'status':'OK', 'address':'address', 'rgb':'rgbImage'})`, I can see the correct data in my browser. Am just not able to send it to a collection in MongoDB.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `insert_one()`?

Comment: `homeReportsCollection.insert_one({'address':address, 'rgb':rgbImage})` still leads to a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Have you tried type casting `address` and `rgbImage` to `String` before inserting?

Comment: I made a typo. Both `address` and `rgbImage` are sent as strings. Just edited my question. So no need to do it on the Python side.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm stumped. There used to be a bug in Mongo back in 2013. The data would be inserted into the collection. But Mongo would not return a correct status response. That led to servers going 500. Have you tried verifying if the data was indeed inserted into the collection? Additionally run your flask app in `debug=True` mode. That might give additional data.

Comment: Do take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993220/inserting-or-saving-into-mongodb-returns-500-server-error . However Py-Mongo should be able to handle this.

Comment: So this is weird, I turned on `debug=True` and I get the following error: `ValueError: View function did not return a response`. BUT the data did actually get sent to DB via `homeReportsCollection.insert({'address':address, 'rgb':rgbImage})` line. I see it in my collection. How do I fix the error? Because the user is redirected to `/recordReport`.

Comment: Try returning something in your function `recordReport()`. Return anything you want. It could be an `OK` message. It could be the `_id` of the document you just inserted into the collection. Just don't return `None`. Try this.

Comment: Yeah, I returned an HTML template and no error now. Thanks for your help. I think it's ok for now. Do you want to post this as answer so I can reward you points?

Comment: Added an answer summarizing the steps and solution. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a summary of the comments (where a solution was found).

---

> Have you tried typecasting `address` and `rgbImage` to `String` before inserting?

Type invalidation is the root of many common bugs in DB operations.

> There used to be a bug in Mongo back in 2013. The data would be inserted into the collection. But Mongo would not return a correct status response. That led to servers going `500`. Have you tried verifying if the data was indeed inserted into the collection?
>
> Additionally run your flask app in `debug=True` mode. That might give additional data.

Flask has very good debug traceback reporting support. This is generally a good idea. In fact this should be the first thing to do when encountering an error.

> So this is weird, I turned on `debug=True` and I get the following error: `ValueError: View function did not return a response.` BUT the data did actually get sent to DB via `homeReportsCollection.insert({'address':address, 'rgb':rgbImage})` line. I see it in my collection. How do I fix the error? Because the user is redirected to `/recordReport`.

So the data was indeed inserted into the collection. It is possibly a Flask only issue. The traceback says it all. Flask requires that something is returned by a view method.

> Try returning something in your function `recordReport()`. Return anything you want. It could be an `OK` message. It could be the `_id` of the document you just inserted into the collection. **Just don't return `None`.** Try this.

This behaviour is documented in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807942/basic-flask-program-returning-500-server-error).

> Yeah, I returned an HTML template and no error now.

This is indeed the solution. Return something other than `None` from your [flask](/questions/tagged/flask) view methods. This also validates the behaviour observed by asker in the question:

> Because if I replace that with `return json.dumps({'status':'OK', 'address':'address', 'rgb':'rgbImage'})`, I can see the correct data in my browser.